# undefined index array pdo

Tags: php, mysql, array, pdo, undefined

bom pessoal estou tentando pegar o id de um usuario que logou e salvar na sessão porem , não esta dando certo , faço uma consulta no banco na hora de logar e transformo o resultado em um array para pegar o id e armazenar na session , mas esta dando undefined index id , ta ai o codigo que faz o login

```
     try{
 $select = ("SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE nome=:usuario AND senha=:senha AND status=1");
 $logarusuario = $pdo->prepare($select);
 $logarusuario->bindValue(":usuario", $usuario);
 $logarusuario->bindValue(":senha", $senha);
 $logarusuario->execute();
 $linhas = $logarusuario->rowCount();
 $result = $logarusuario->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);


 if($linhas > 0){
    $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;
    $_SESSION['senha'] = $senha;
    $_SESSION['id'] = $result['id'];
    $_SESSION['logged_success'] = 'você foi logado com sucesso';
    header(5,"Location:../logado.php");
   }else{
    header("Location:../index.php");
    echo "Dados Digitados Incorretos";
   }
}catch(PDOException $e){
   echo $e;
}
?>
```

Comment: Ao usar `PDO::FETCH_OBJ` vc troca os `[]` por `->`

Comment: Também, ao usar o `fetchAll` ele vai retornar uma coleção. Trocar o `[]` por `->` seria o caso de usar dentro de um _loop_, `foreach` por exemplo.

Answer (score 0):

A função fetchAll retorna um array multidimensional. Você não deveria fazer apenas `$result['id']`. Exemplo do que é retornado:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1

        ),
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2

        )
)
```

Então, você poderia fazer `$result[0]['id']`, supondo que haverá pelo sempre um usuário retornado nesse trecho do código.